# Cannot add property to INamingContainer in Web User Control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls

The code I have *(below)* works except for when I add the `ref="abc"` to the `TemplateItem` tag. When it is included I get this error:

> Property 'TemplateItem' does not have a property named 'ref'

How do I resolve this issue?

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Register Src="~/message.ascx" TagName="Message" TagPrefix="uc" %>

<uc:Message ID="msg" runat="server" abc="123" >
    <TemplateItem ref="abc">Hi</TemplateItem>
</uc:Message>
```

message.ascx

```
<asp:placeholder runat="server" id="PlaceHolder1" />
```

message.ascx.vb

```
Partial Class message
Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

    Public Property abc() As String

    Sub Page_Init()
        If TemplateItem IsNot Nothing Then
            TemplateItem.InstantiateIn(PlaceHolder1)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private m_TemplateItem As ITemplate = Nothing

    <TemplateContainer(GetType(TemplateItem2))> _
    Public Property TemplateItem() As ITemplate
        Get
            Return m_TemplateItem
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As ITemplate)
            m_TemplateItem = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Class TemplateItem2
        Inherits Control
        Implements INamingContainer

        Public Property ref() As String
    End Class

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it should be:

```
Public Class TemplateItem2
```

at the bottom there, and not just the following?:

```
Public Class TemplateItem
```

(If you just want a different name from the property, maybe something like `TemplateItemImplementation` or just `TemplateItemImpl` would be more clear?)

Also, I'm not sure how this works:

```
    TemplateItem.InstantiateIn(PlaceHolder1)
```

The [MSDN page on CompiledTemplate.InstantiateIn()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.compiledtemplatebuilder.instantiatein%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) says: *This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.* I guess this is a sidenote though, and I'm assuming you've gotten it to work the way you want...

I think the problem is related to the instantiation of `TemplateItem` in that line though; I can not see how `TemplateItem2` (which contains the property `ref()`) is related to `ITemplateItem`. Maybe you just need to make `TemplateItem2` also implement `ITemplateItem`?

Another thing to try is to make `ref()` a property of `ITemplateItem`, if possible. Maybe that Interface becomes the Type of `<TemplateItem />`, which would explain why it does not contain the property `Ref`?.

(That is assuming the type is specified by the return type of the property `TemplateItem()`).